# Jquery, target parent div if hasClass

Tags: jquery

I have a couple of posts that looks like this ("test" being the posts):

```
<div class="test">
      <p><a href="">test</a></p>
      <span class="thumbs-rating-up thumbs-rating-voted" onclick="thumbs_rating_vote(4, 1);" data-text="Vote Up"> +1</span>
</div>

<div class="test">
       <p><a href="">test</a></p>
       <span class="thumbs-rating-up" onclick="thumbs_rating_vote(4, 1);" data-text="Vote Up"> +1</span>
</div>
```

As you can see. some of these posts has the class `thumbs-rating-voted`. What I'd like to do is to add a class to the post link if the post has that class.

I've tried this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        setTimeout(function() {
                if ($('.thumbs-rating-up').hasClass('thumbs-rating-voted')) {
                $('#test p > a').addClass('hide-voted-image');
                alert('test');
                }  
        }, 3000);
});
```

But it affects all posts, as seen in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Ndt4/3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, ID's **must** be unique! Secondly, you'll have to loop thru each of these div's and check the class individually and go from there, but why do that when you can just loop the class your checking for and add the class to the anchor:

```
$(".thumbs-rating-voted").each(function() {
    $(this).prev("p").find("a").addClass("hide-voted-image");
});
```

Or, as nicely pointed out by @DavidThomas

```
$(".thumbs-rating-voted").prev("p").find("a").addClass("hide-voted-image")
```

Comment: I don't think you need the `each()`, I'm pretty certain that you can just chain: `$(".thumbs-rating-voted").prev("p").find("a").addClass("hide-voted-image");`

Comment: @DavidThomas -- Ahh yup - overlooked that, edited and added, thanks!

Comment: New to jquery, starting to get the hang of it, thanks! It worked wonders